# Citation for the definition of Return on Investment

Tags: expected-return, investment

I am writing a paper in an area where the concept of [Return on Investment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_investment) may not be clear. Is there a definitive source for its definition I can cite?

Answer (score 1):

Any textbook on corporate finance contains the formula for ROI. Below are two popular ones,

Berk and De Marzo - Corporate Finance

Bodie, Kane, Marcus - Investments

Comment: Is there a book with a freely downloadable pdf?

Comment: i found the pdf for both free. try different search engines